# How can I use a parameter from a stored procedure in another procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am created an online staff rota application. I have a stored procedure for each day of the week with an auto increment primary key for the `Rota` table. Each day within the selected week will have the same `rota ID` as a foreign key.

I have no problem with the first selected day but the following days return NULL for the foreign key `RotaID` as I don't know how to pass the `RotaID` into the other stored procedures to ensure the `RotaID` remains the same for the 7 days of the weekly `Rota`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_RotaDay1]

@Week_Begin datetime, 
@Week_End datetime,

@1ShiftDate datetime,
@1Day nchar (10),

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @RotaID int
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM Rota 
WHERE Week_Begin = @Week_Begin
AND
Week_End = @Week_End
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Rota
 (
 [Week_Begin], 
 [Week_End]
 )

VALUES
 (
 @Week_Begin,
 @Week_End
 )
END

SELECT @RotaID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM DayShift
WHERE ShiftDate = @1ShiftDate
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO DayShift

 (
 [RotaID],
 [ShiftDate],
 [Day]
 )

 VALUES
 (
 @RotaID,
 @1ShiftDate,
 @1Day
 )
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

As you can see I have the `RotaID` declared in the `Rota` table and then passed as the foreign key in the `DayShift` table.

I would like to know if it is possible to pass this through to my other stored procedures which are similar to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of your secondary stored procedures, you need to retrieve the primary key id using a select statement. You know weekbegin and weekend for all your secondary procedures right? so you know which row to pull to retrieve the id. Hope I made sense.

Comment: @Brain thanks for this, it has provided me with a quick fix. I just select the RotaID WHERE shiftdate BETWEEN weekbegin and weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to return the `@RotaID` parameter value to the calling program for use in a future procedure call, you can specify the parameter as `OUTPUT`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_RotaDay1]
(
    @Week_Begin datetime, 
    @Week_End datetime,

    @1ShiftDate datetime,
    @1Day nchar (10),
    @RotaID int OUTPUT
)
AS
    ...
```

Comment: I have tried this although because I declare the RotaID parameter further down in the code I get errors when trying to specify as output. I think I need to reorganise my code in order to set RotaID to output

Comment: @Danny You wouldn't DECLARE it anymore as specifying it as OUTPUT takes the place of a declaration.